# Does template matching using Gaussian filter (pyramid) give poor results?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am attempting to perform template matching using pyramid representation, but getting bad results. I am unsure if the bad results are due to a problem with my algorithm/code or because that is just the result.

The code follows, but I have basically taken an image, converted it to grayscale, cropped the image to get a template, scaled the template, implemented the sliding window method for matching each of the pyramid images (scaled image) to the query image using the metrics Zero-mean Correlation, SSD, and NCC, and determined the localization error

```py
# Load the images
image1 = cv2.imread("image1.jpg")

# Convert the images to grayscale
gray_image1 = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Crop the image
y_1 = 100
x_1 = 100
w_1 = 15
h_1 = 15
template_image1 = gray_image1[y_1:y_1 + h_1, x_1:x_1 + w_1].copy()

# Scale the template image
template_image1_5 = cv2.resize(template_image1, None, fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
template_image1_1 = cv2.resize(template_image1, None, fx=1.0, fy=1.0, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
template_image1_2 = cv2.resize(template_image1, None, fx=2.0, fy=2.0, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

# Store the scaled template and their associated scaling factors in a dictionary
scaled_templates_image1 = {'0.5': template_image1_5, '1.0': template_image1_1, '2.0': template_image1_2}

# Put the three different methods (Zero-mean correlation, SSD, and NCC) in a list
methods = ['cv2.TM_CCORR', 'cv2.TM_SQDIFF', 'cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED']

for meth in methods:
    method = eval(meth)

    # Apply template matching
    for scale, scaled_template_image1 in scaled_templates_image1.items():
        gray_image1_copy = gray_image1.copy()

        result = cv2.matchTemplate(gray_image1_copy, scaled_template_image1, method)
        min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

        # If the method is TM_SQDIFF, then take the minimum
        if method in [cv2.TM_SQDIFF]:
            top_left = min_loc
        else:
            top_left = max_loc
        bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w_3, top_left[1] + h_3)

        cv2.rectangle(gray_image1_copy, top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)

        print(meth, top_left, bottom_right)

        euclidean_distance = np.linalg.norm(np.subtract((x_1, y_1), top_left))
        print("The localization error for the " + scale + " scale using " + meth + " method is: " +
              np.str(euclidean_distance))

        plt.subplot(121), plt.imshow(result, cmap='gray')
        plt.title('Matching Result'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
        plt.subplot(122), plt.imshow(gray_image1_copy, cmap='gray')
        plt.title('Detected Point'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
        plt.suptitle("The " + scale + " scale using " + meth + " method")

        plt.show()
```

The localization errors are everywhere. Without scaling, the localization errors for SSD and NCC are 0.0, while the localization error for Zero-mean correlation is above 100 (expected). When applying scaling, the localization errors are almost all above 100. Am I going about this wrong or should I just expect such results? Maybe I'm not understanding the concept and-or problem correctly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you look at the template and image at each of the scales to see if they makes sense?

Comment: Yes and template image at each of the scales comes out looking as a mix of yellow, blue, and green pixels. I have a feeling I'm not doing something right. Still working on it...